# Why is this sentence a complete sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

"He and others find that these mRNA's direct,in large part,the synthesis of histones, a class of proteins that bind to DNA. "

It seems to me that perhaps the main verb is "is" (mRNA is direct). But I don't see a connection like a preposition between "mRNA's direct" and "the synthesis of histone".
Also, there is a "is" - "mRNA's ", so I assume direct couldn't be a verb.

I can understand there are a subject, a main verb, and a main object. Seems everything is in there. But this sentence still seems weird to me. Why is this sentence a complete sentence?
"mRNA's direct the synthesis of histones" : Looks weird to me.

Source: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/206/4416/315 Or you may view the below screenshot if it can not be zoom in.

[image]

Comment: There actually is no *is*: "mRNA's" is the plural of mRNA, because some people use an apostrophe to make an abbreviation plural.  Does that help you understand the sentence better?

Comment: Duplicate of [this closed post on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/570790/216106).

Comment: It said I couldn't post this type of question on ELU and recommend me post here, so I post here

Comment: stangdon - Thank you. You solved my question!

Comment: What makes you think the 'main' verb is "is"? Where is it?

Comment: That "mRNA's" - made me think it's "mRNA is direct"; nevertheless, stangdon solved my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In large part" is an [idiomatic](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+large+part) way of saying '*mostly*'.

When a phrase is enclosed in parenthetical commas, as this is, you should be able to read the sentence without it and it make grammatical sense. Let's also take the explanation of histones as being parenthetic and look at the sentence now:

> He and others find that these mRNA's direct the synthesis of histones.

The sentence is perfectly grammatical.

That isn't to say that the parenthetical information should be ignored - it is important to the statement that these findings were only correct *in the main*. The explanation of what histones are is presumably also useful, unless the reader already knows this information.

Note that the apostrophe in "mRNA's" does not denote a possessive or a contraction. Apostrophes are sometimes used to separate the 's' when the plural is an initialism. This is to avoid any confusion that the 's' might be part of it. That is especially useful when the abbreviation contains both upper and lower case characters, as *mRNA* does.

Comment: "sometimes used to separate the 's' when the plural is an **abbreviation**" should be "sometimes used to separate the 's' when the plural is an **acronym**". It is not normal to use an apostrophe for an abbreviation, for example "Sarah sent me the sales **stats** this morning".

Comment: Thank you. The part regarding apostrophe solved my question. Really helpful!

Comment: @JavaLatte mRNA is not an acronym. If it is, please can you tell me how to pronounce it?

Comment: You should also point out that the main verb here is “find”.

Comment: @StephenS I think the OP was only struggling to identify the verb because they were confused by the construction. Now that I've deconstructed it, this should be obvious - and they have already said that it has solved their question.

Comment: @Astralbee it is an acronym for Messenger Ribo Nucleic Acid.  it is pronounced /ˌem.ɑːr.enˈeɪ/. Also, see this english SE question: the answer suggests that it is no longer acceptable to add an apostrophe, even for acronyms. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not

Comment: @JavaLatte Ah, now I see. You're confusing acronyms with initialisms. 'mRNA' is **not** an acronym because you don't pronounce it as a word. 'AIDS' is an acronym. And the question here is not whether it is acceptable or not - the OP has asked for a sample text to be explained, and this text *has* used it.

Comment: I didn't read the answer carefully so I also thought it's because of acronym at first..Now I read more carefully and know it's because of initialism, not acronym...and also learn there is a difference between acronums and initialism....haha

Comment: @ChrissyChien Good to know! Yes, just imagine if you had an initialism like 'PiS' (patient information system). You wouldn't want to make that an acronym because it would sound like you're saying "piss". And, if you wanted to refer to such systems in plural, that's when an apostrophe may well be used (PiS's) otherwise you'd just be writing 'PiSS'.